# How to apply css on a div that has no class or id?

Tags: html, css

I have two div and I want to apply some css on the first div that has no class or id .How can I do it ??

Html:

```
<div>some content</div>

<div class="text-1">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `:not()` selector:

```css
div:not([class]) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>some content</div>

<div class="text-1">some more</div>
```

Basically this says select any div that doesn't have the `class` attribute.